# What's the best way to infer the callback argument type from a union type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a helper that let's me subscribe to a specific *type* of dispatched actions in a React app. These are the action interfaces I'm working with:

```ts
enum ActionTypes {
  MoveToLine = 'MOVE_TO_LINE',
  MoveToColumn = 'MOVE_TO_COLUMN',
}

interface MoveToLineAction {
  type: ActionTypes.MoveToLine;
  payload: { line: number };
}

interface MoveToColumnAction {
  type: ActionTypes.MoveToColumn;
  payload: { column: number };
}

type Actions = MoveToLineAction | MoveToColumnAction;
```

And here's the implementation of `subscribeToAction`:

```ts
const subscribeToAction = <A extends { type: string }, T extends ActionTypes>(
  type: T,
  onAction: (a: A) => void,
) => (action: A) => {
  if (action.type === type) {
    onAction(action);
  }
};
```

I want to be able to use it like this:

```ts
// Subscribe to a specific type of action
subscribeToAction(ActionTypes.MoveToLine, action => {
  action.payload.line;
});
```

The problem I'm running into is that I want the type of `action` in the `onAction` listener to be inferred automatically. In the code above, I get a `Property 'payload' does not exist on type '{ type: string; }'` error. I can manually type the listener to get around this like this:

```ts
subscribeToAction(ActionTypes.MoveToLine, (action: MoveToLineAction) => {
  action.payload.line;
});
```

But it seems redundant to pass in an `ActionType` and then also have to specify the action type in the listener. Do you guys have any suggestions as to how to avoid doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd go about it:

```
type ActionOfType<T extends ActionTypes> = Extract<Actions, { type: T }>;

const subscribeToAction = <T extends ActionTypes>(
    type: T,
    onAction: (a: ActionOfType<T>) => void,
) => (action: Actions) => {
    if (action.type === type) {
        // assertion necessary or explicit type guard: 
        onAction(action as ActionOfType<T>);
    }
};

subscribeToAction(ActionTypes.MoveToLine,
    action => { // action inferred as MoveToLineAction
        action.payload.line;
    }
);
```

You don't really want two generic parameters in `subscribeToAction()`.  You want `T` corresponding to the `ActionTypes` constituent passed in as `type`, and you want the argument to the `onAction` callback to automatically be constrained to the corresponding constituent of `Actions`.  The `ActionOfType<T>` type function shows how you can do this.  Oh, and the return value of `subscribeToAction` should be a function that takes *any* `Actions`, right?  That's why you do the `if (action.type === type)` check.

Also note that because `action` is of type `Actions`, you need to tell the compiler that the test `if (action.type === type)` actually narrows `action` down to `ActionOfType<T>`.  I just use a type assertion.

Okay, hope that helps you.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I'm looking for. Didn't know about `Extract`. I'll give it a shot. :)